# Pdf generate in hebrew language using dompdf libraray

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

I create PDFs using the dompdf library. The pdf is generating fine, however I want to translate the content into Hebrew.
According to the documentation, https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/About-Fonts-and-Character-Encoding. I added hebrew fonts.
However, it isn't working and the content is still being translated to this "???????????????????"

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'hebrew_custom_attach_to_wc_emails', 10, 3);
function hebrew_custom_attach_to_wc_emails($attachments, $email_id, $order)
{


    if (!is_a($order, 'WC_Order') || !isset($email_id)) {
        return $attachments;
    }
    $file_path = 'none'; // directory of the current theme

    // Generate the PDF content

    $pdf_content = generate_custom_pdf_content($order);

    // Create a new instance of Dompdf
    $font_path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Hebrew.ttf';
    // $font_read = file_get_contents($font_path);
    $options = new Options();
    $tmp = sys_get_temp_dir();
    $options->set('defaultFont', 'Noto Sans Hebrew');
    $dompdf = new Dompdf([
        'logOutputFile' => '',
        // authorize DomPdf to download fonts and other Internet assets
        'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
        // all directories must exist and not end with /
        'fontDir' => $tmp,
        'fontCache' => $tmp,
        'tempDir' => $tmp,
        'chroot' => $tmp,
    ]);
    if ($dompdf) {
        $dompdf->loadHtml($pdf_content);

        // Set paper size and orientation (optional)
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

        // Render the PDF
        $dompdf->render();

        // Get the PDF content
        $pdf_output = $dompdf->output();
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $upload_path = $upload_dir['basedir'];

        // Generate a unique filename for the PDF
        $pdf_filename = 'invoice-hebrew' . uniqid() . '.pdf';

        // Build the full path to save the PDF in the upload directory
        $pdf_full_path = $upload_path . '/' . $pdf_filename;

        // Save the PDF in the upload directory
        file_put_contents($pdf_full_path, $pdf_output);

        // Attach the PDF to the WooCommerce email
        $attachments[] = $pdf_full_path;

        return $attachments;
    } else {
        $attachments[] = $file_path;
        return $attachments;
    }
    // Load HTML content into Dompdf

}
```

function contains the html of pdf

```
ob_start(); // Start output buffering
                $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod('custom_logo');
                $image = 'https://booking.wemates.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/logo_WeMate.svg';
                $logo_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image)); // Fetch and encode the image content

                $signature_img_path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/signature-wemates.png';
                $signature_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($signature_img_path));



                echo "<html>
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Hebrew:wght@300;400&display=swap' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Hebrew:wght@300;400&display=swap');
.m {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Hebrew', sans-serif';
}
</style>
                </head>
                <body> <div class='m'> <table class='head container'><tr><td class='header'>";

                echo '<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,' . $logo_base64 . '" width="200" alt="Site Logo">';

                echo '</td>';

    echo '</div></body></html>'; 

                $content = ob_get_clean(); // Get the content from the buffer and end buffering
                return $content;
```

PDF:

[PDF Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0fWM.png)